# Outlook says "Updating Inbox 3.99GB" and doesn't download mails (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, office365

Well this was a very well known issue as the title explains but in my case, the "**updating inbox 3.99GB**" keeps on repeating to the same state. No new mail activities or even download progress on Inbox, but the other folders at least updating upon selecting.

I can see about 23K mails when I check the synchronization through the inbox properties. And somehow, it had updated up to 15K and now nothing happens. To be exact, I have created a new profile and kept it to download but still the problem persists.

I do not know what else to do with this. I can assure there's no issue as other users are able to communicate without any issues.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This actually has an answer from Microsoft here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2738323 Basically, the file size is too big, and the status bar only indicates up to 3.99GB.

Comment: I've referred to it but unfortunately none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

How long have you waited? It appears like what @RDrast has already pointed out.  If you feel the issue is not resolving itself I would recommend checking out the Outlook Support and Recovery Assistant Here:  https://configure.office.com/sara/SetupE.exe

Consider changing how much email you are downloading as well to keep offline.  Start low - and you can increase it as you validate it if you need too.  If your not aware of where to do this - it's under your account settings (File --> Account) right on the first page, there is a slider for how much offline mail to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.I did compact now and then everything was alright. That update bar is no longer stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of mail flow in exchange server.
Reduce the size of mail from inbox.
Move inbox mail by creating PST folder.
Mail will download automatically.
You can follow Microsoft SOP.